# Multi-level association, not saving parent tables id

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0

I have 3 tables:

```
colleges (id, name)
departments (id, name, college_id)
students (id, name, college_id, department_id)
```

and the following associations:

```
colleges hasMany departments
departments hasMany students
students belongsTo departments
```

The issue is that when I tried to save data at a time for all of these tables, data saved successfully, but the foreign key `college_id` didn't save in the `students` table. Excluding this, everything was perfectly okay.

Got `college_id` in `departments` table, got `department_id` in `student` table, but didn't get the `college_id` in the `student` table.

EDIT:-
Bellow is the array structure, I am getting in my action

```
name => 'KITT',
departments => [
          0 => [
               name => 'ETC'
               students => [
                   0 => [
                      name => 'Bikash'
                   ],
                   1 => [
                      name => 'Nancy'
                   ]
          ]
    ],
          1 => [
                name => 'CSE'
                students => [
                   0 => [
                      name => 'Czy'
                   ],
                   1 => [
                      name => 'ABY'
                   ]
          ]

]
```

And my save code is

```
$entity = $this->Colleges->newEntity($this->request->data, [
                     'associated' => ['Departments.Students']
         ]);
$this->Colleges->save($entity, ['associated' =>'Departments.Students'])
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code for the action in which you save the data, and also the template for the view.

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please help me out @InigoFlores

Comment: Why would there be a `college_id` in the `students` table to begin with? This would only make any sense in case `Students` would have an association with `Colleges`, and could exist without `Departments` and/or `Departments` could exist without being associated to `Colleges`. In any case the ORM doesn't support saving such, let's call them "parallel-associations".

Comment: You are riight @ndm, actually I am converting a old site to new. I am working with the old DB structure that is forcing me to do the same. Okay thanks for your response, will do it by manually adding... :)

Comment: @ndm I think this would be a case of *loop of dependent relationships*. [See page 11 of this paper](http://ooatool.com/docs/OOA96.pdf). The `colleges hasMany students` association is redundant, as this information can be derived from `colleges hasMany departments hasMany students`, and is consired bad practice to model it, **unless** you are denormalizing your database. Can you confirm the ORM does not support saving these loop associations?

Comment: @InigoFlores Yeah, kinda looks like what is being shown here, good to have proper wording for that :) I'm pretty sure that the ORM is only capable of saving associations in a linear manner, as the association saving functionality will only receive information about the immediate parent (the parent entity). It might be possible to handle this using custom association classes that pass the main entity and/or information about which possible foreign keys to use from the parent along the saving process.